# version on central.ballerina.io/ballerinax/sfdc is not the latest

Tags: ballerina

The latest released sfdc ballerinax package version on the repo is [7.2.0](https://github.com/ballerina-platform/module-ballerinax-sfdc/releases), while that on ballerina central is [3.0.1](https://central.ballerina.io/ballerinax/sfdc).
Am I looking at this correctly? How do I consume the latest sfdc package?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ballerina/sfdc` is deprecated. That package is now renamed as `ballerinax/salesforce`

Please refer the below links
https://central.ballerina.io/ballerinax/salesforce/7.2.0
https://lib.ballerina.io/ballerinax/salesforce/7.2.0